# Images not displaying on MediaWiki 1.16

Tags: image, mediawiki

In this [wiki](http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/jurapedia/mediawiki) that I recently set up, the images are not displayed. I tried both local uploads and InstantCommons (like I did in the main page), but the result is the same. The software is 1.16.5 and I cannot upgrade it since the hosting server only supports a PHP compatible to this MediaWiki version at the best. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the images directory?

Comment: I tried different value, such as 644 (advised by the web team of my university, however, by using this one I got even an error message in the top of my wiki when clicking images), 755, or 777, but the problem stuck and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I solved my problem, it just required to add some instruction to create independent links for uploaded images.

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer so that other people can benefit from your experience. :)

Comment: @Danilo, you meant to use the "Add answer" button. :) You can now click the check mark to signify that the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Danilo's own answer: I solved the problem. My `LocalSettings.php` was missing:

```
$wgUploadPath = "$wgScriptPath/uploads";
$wgUploadDirectory = "$IP/uploads";
```

which were needed to allow independent creations of URL.